# Why is SELinux still disabled eventhough CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX is enabled in the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, selinux

I am compiling Linux kernel v3.12.61 with PREEMPT-RT patch in Yocto (1.8.1 Fido) with the following kernel configuration enabled. The `/sys/fs/selinux` directory is created but it is empty.

```
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=1 
 #CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE is not set 
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_AVC_STATS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE=1
 #CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_POLICYDB_VERSION_MAX is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
```

Regardless of whether I enable `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM` or set it `0` or `1`, the result is still the same.

I have installed the SELinux userspace tools using the meta-selinux layer from OE. I also set `SELINUX=permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`. Running `sestatus` returns `"SELinux status: disabled"`. Previously that was all I needed to do when compiling an older kernel (v3.2). Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `meta-selinux` layer](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/about/) has a section that pretty much outlines what to do if you want to use selinux in your images.

For the sake of Stack Overflow completeness I will paste it in here, but please be aware that this state might be outdated when you read it here, so please always refer to the original if possible.

### Building the meta-selinux layer

> In order to add selinux support to the poky build this layer should be added to your projects bblayers.conf file.
>
> By default the selinux components are disabled.  This conforms to the Yocto Project compatible guideline that indicate that simply including a layer should not change the system behavior.
>
> In order to use the components in this layer you must add the 'selinux' to the `DISTRO_FEATURES`.  In addition to selinux, you should be sure that `acl`, `xattr` and `pam` are also present. e.g. `DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " acl xattr pam selinux"`
>
> You must also specify a preferred provider for the virtual/refpolicy.  The included policies with this layer are simply reference policies and will need to be tailored for your environment.
>
> Enable the refpolicy-mls: e.g. `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/refpolicy ?= "refpolicy-mls"`

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation previously, but instead of `DISTRO_FEATURES`, I appended to `MACHINE_FEATURES` and thought it would be the same. As a result, the systemd bbapend file from `meta-selinux` which only checks `DISTRO_FEATURES` did not detect this change and therefore not compiled with `--with-selinux`.